# Headless Chrome command line - set timeout

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, cmd, delay, headless

I'm trying to print pdf from Gmail with headless chrome in command line.

I cannot install pupeteer or another tool with the computer that script will run on, due to unability to install anything.

For simple gsuite pages such as https://myaccount.google.com/, my script runs perfectly.

For more complex ones such as gmail, the output PDF I get shows a partially loaded page:
[output PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMQsE.png)

I'm already using the *--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw* option which should wait for the page to resolve before printing.

I've tried to add *--virtual-time-budget=10000* just before *--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw*, however if I ask for more than 2000 milliseconds the command runs for ever without producing the output pdf.

See my code so far below (which I put in a .bat file)

Does anyone have encountered that issue ? Any lead on how to solve it ? Any ways to first load the page, then have a timeout command, then print to pdf ?

I couldn't find a solution so far on the web.

Thanks :)

Ps: english isn't my primary language, please excuse any mistake

```
@set outputFile=C:\Users\MyUserName\Temp\testPDFprintChromeheadless\test.pdf
@set chromeDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
@set url=https://mail.google.com/mail/

@set userData=C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
@set profile=MyChromeProfile

@set useragentChrome="Mozilla/5.0 (X11\\; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36"

@cd "%chromeDirectory%"
chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --profile-directory="%profile%" --user-data-dir="%userData%" --user-agent=%useragentChrome% --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf="%outputFile%" --print-to-pdf-no-header "%url%"
pause
```

Edit :
Here are the logs I get.

AccÞs refusÚ means Accès refusé which is french for Access denied.

I don't have administrator rights on this computer, thus not able to write within the Chrome directory, that could explain this access denied.

```
[0820/101506.995:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: AccÞs refusÚ. (0x5)
[0820/101506.996:ERROR:cache_util.cc(144)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\GPUCache to C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[0820/101506.997:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0820/101506.997:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0820/101509.033:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: AccÞs refusÚ. (0x5)
[0820/101509.034:ERROR:cache_util.cc(144)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache to C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\old_Cache_000
[0820/101509.035:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0820/101510.020:ERROR:service_worker_storage.cc(1899)] Failed to delete the database: Database IO error
[0820/101513.168:INFO:CONSOLE(1763)] "Deprecated API for given entry type.", source: https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/_/js/k=gmail.main.fr.YnGL5qwRpj4.O/am=rvxfykdgoP_swM-GUSAcAAM5SAABYIUsYuW09wdKmv8BAwAGoG_F8GAQrnkAdJzCuAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADsAisGAQ/d=1/exm=b/ed=1/im=1/dg=0/br=1/wt=1/rs=AHGWq9AzRZEBJ1Ek7NOabODYvaA7PPmCUQ/cb=loaded_1/m=a (1763)
[0820/101519.465:INFO:headless_shell.cc(648)] Written to file C:\Users\MyUserName\Temp\testPDFprintChromeheadless\test.pdf.
```

Comment: Have you defined the variables `%directoryOut%` and `%filename%`?

Comment: @aschiplf : yes I did, my mistake when I simplified the code. I'm editing 1st post right now.

@K J : will try to --enable-logging & see what gets out of it. FYI logging into google with headless is possible without user input (based on the google chrome connected profile), and that's working currently